# Пунктуация от М. Булгакова. Перечисление

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь, перечисление

> Произошла суматоха, и в ней отчетливее всего были слышны три фразы:
> Филиппа Филипповича: «Валерьянки! Это обморок».
> Доктора Борменталя: «Швондера я собственноручно сброшу с лестницы, если он еще раз появится в квартире профессора Преображенского».
> И Швондера: «Прошу занести эти слова в протокол!»

В эпилоге повести перечисляемые фразы идут красной строкой — с прописной и заканчиваются точкой. Есть ощущение недоработки, если когда и попадающейся где-либо, то скорее в технической книге. А можно ли было найти иное (изящное, под стать произведению) решение, к которому было бы «нечего предъявить»?

https://reading-books.me/prosa/slassic-proza/page,18,1729-sobache-serdce.html

Answer (score 4):

Для сравнения приведу оформление многоголосья из книги "Маугли" Р. Д. Киплинга.

> — ...Трудно ли принять решение?
> Поднялся гул голосов, звучало:
> — Стоит ли рассуждать? Он умрет от зимних дождей; солнце сожжет его! Какой вред может принести нам безволосая лягушка? Пусть себе бегает со стаей. А где бык, Багира? Примем детеныша!
> И все закончил глубокий лающий голос Акелы:
> — Смотрите хорошенько, смотрите хорошенько, о волки!

Здесь автору не важно, кому конкретно из зверей принадлежат высказывания. Он дает их одной строкой, подряд.

Булгакову же, думаю, при большом количестве присутствующих в комнате и, соответственно, при всей многофразности ситуации, хотелось отчетливо выделить только три голоса, причем очень коротко (без слов "говорения" — как в пьесе).

Для изящности же и для того, чтобы было "нечего предъявить", достаточно заменить первое двоеточие (а вообще, было ли оно у Булгакова?) точкой.
Это возможно, потому что *особенных* слов в предложении нет.

> **2.** Между частями бессоюзного сложного предложения **двоеточие** ставится обязательно, если в первой части имеются слова ***так, таков, такой, одно*** и т. п., конкретное содержание которых раскрывается во второй части...

Такое оформление, кстати, встречается гораздо чаще. И, как мне кажется, не вызывает никаких сомнений.

[Литература. 11 класс. Хрестоматия...](https://books.google.ee/books?id=YC8kEAAAQBAJ&pg=PA264&lpg=PA264&dq=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%B0,%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%BD%D1%8B%20%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%20%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B:&source=bl&ots=k_WUbcAGSU&sig=ACfU3U04XG-WBgqiYoAWMjgRHMd_GbrtKw&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi5oazAx6v9AhUtlosKHQ9DDCoQ6AF6BAgVEAM#v=onepage&q=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%B0%2C%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%BD%D1%8B%20%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%20%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%3A&f=false)
[Михаил Булгаков. Том 3](https://e-knigi.com/proza/klassicheskaja-proza/page-31-139538-mihail-bulgakov-tom-3-sobache-serdce.html)
[Михаил Булгаков. Сочинения](http://m-bulgakov.ru/sochineniya/sobache-serdce/p10)
[Двоеточие в бессоюзном сложном предложении](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=150#pp150)
[Фильм](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%8C%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B4%D1%86%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C&oq=&aqs=chrome.1.69i59i450l8.1311322j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#fpstate=ive&vld=cid:7cfb2d57,vid:z2BQMwZjMCE) (2.10.00)

Comment: Римма, надо бы как-то исправить "чтобы нечего предъявить". И ссылка **2.10.00** (я так понимаю, это время) ведет на целый ряд видео.

Comment: Саша, теперь глянь-посмотри. А ссылка — это фильм. Чуть подожди — и выскочит. У меня все хорошо.

Comment: Ждал, ничего не выскакивает... :) Перешел на одно из... и там первая фраза "Валерьянки" на 2.11.10. Ну это всё мелочи.